VSCode stuck in "EXPLORER:DEPENDENCIES" instead of plain "EXPLORER"
I tried to create new application with flutter via VSCode.
After selection of location and name for app I can't see the folder tree in my EXPLORER window n VSCode. I'm stuck with EXPLORER:DEPENDENCIES.
Open folder doesn't help. Add dependency causing a circular dependency.

Do you have any idea?
